# How to pass data to a custom event via EventTarget prototype?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, custom-events

I'm following this [blog post](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/) on creating custom events using an EventTarget prototype. In my case this `EventTarget` object needs to be modified to return `data` to the `onDataEvent` listener:

```
o.onDataEvent("foo", function(data){
    var dataRetrieved = data.message; //retrieve data object passed to fire function
    console.log(dataRetrieved); //undefined
    alert("Foo just happened.");
});
```

So I made a gist based on [this blog post](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/) in a JSFiddle where I've overridden the `EventTarget.fire` function which dispatches the event, to accept a second argument of *data*.

And also modified the onDataEvent signature to include a data param. The idea here is that in addition to calling `event("foo")` I would return some data to the event.

I know the event is called via `listeners[i].call(this, event);` But I'm not clear on how I could pass data back in the `.call`.

**Question:**

How can you pass data to a custom event via an EventTarget prototype?

This is a gist of that code: https://jsfiddle.net/hLj7yxw9/8/

During debugging I verified that the event is called using this pattern as you can see in the above fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `data` as `listeners[i].call(this, event, data)`

Then in your listener do:

```
o.onDataEvent("foo", function(event, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hLj7yxw9/9/

Comment: ok I see and to match the event definition directly to only return `data` in params it would be https://jsfiddle.net/hLj7yxw9/10/

Comment: yea that looks fine.